# Is there a way to align labels in MSChart line charts?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart

I am using MSChart in Visual Studio 2013 and am getting some really weird results. On a line chart, when graphing the points, the labels show lower valued points as higher on the chart, which is visually confusing. See the following:

[image]

The chart labels are set as follows:

```
        recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].BorderWidth = 3;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].Color = Color.Red;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].LabelBackColor = Color.Red;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].LabelBorderColor = Color.Black;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].LabelBorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].LabelBorderWidth = 1;
            recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].LabelForeColor = Color.White;
        SmartLabelStyle smartLabel = new SmartLabelStyle();
        smartLabel.AllowOutsidePlotArea = LabelOutsidePlotAreaStyle.Partial;
        smartLabel.IsMarkerOverlappingAllowed = true;
        recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].SmartLabelStyle = smartLabel;
```

in the constructor and in the function adding the points:

```
        recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].Points.InsertY(0, failCount);
        recentFailureChart.Series["FailureCount"].Points[0].Font = labelFont;
```

Any ideas on how to get them in the correct order, or even over the points themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the attached Chart Image above, the points 14 and 12 are properly plotted above the lower points of 5, 3 and 1. The only thing I notice is, not all the points are visible in the chart, this can be changed by setting the maximum value of your Y-axis to  higher value like 100 using, Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Maximum = 100.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the properties you are looking for are these:

```
MaxMovingDistance  
MinMovingDistance  
MovingDirection  
AllowOutsidePlotArea
```

A. Set AllowOutsidePlotArea if it is acceptable for the label to overlap the X-Axis.

B. Set MovingDirection to Top in order to force all labels to be displayed over the DataPoint.

C. You could also make the X-Axis cross the Y-Axis on -2 or something similar, making room for the smartlabels inside the plotarea.